# Iterate through range of dates in scala

Tags: scala

How can I make sure o_data below appends multiple files? Assuming there's one file (Tab separated Values) for each date (starting in 2018-09-01), I'd like to append all 30 files (9/1~9/30) and store it in the o_data variable. My initial guess would be to use for loop, but not being not familiar with scala, not sure where to start.

The below works for one file.

```
val o_data = "test::repo/shared/[2018-09-01]"
```

Then I use

```
val data = tes.read(o_data)
```

to read the file, but in order for me to get a full month's of data, the only thing I can do is to create different val for each of the file, so o_data2, o_data3 ... o_data30, and run the read function for each of the file and combine it at the end, but that sounds silly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
    val o_data = (1 to 30).map(d => {
      val df = if(d<10) "0"+d else d 
      s"test::repo/shared/[2018-09-$df]"
    })
```

After the above, `o_data` will be:

```
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-01]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-02]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-03]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-04]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-05]
...
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-28]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-29]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-30]
```

The idea is to use Scala's [string interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) to construct the right filename from a number. The `if` statement ensures that there will be a `0` before the number if it is less than 10.

**Edit:** If you like one liners (as I do), the above can be re-written as (again using the capabalities string interploation offers and thanks to [@Dima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939230/iterate-through-range-of-dates-in-scala/52939359#comment92788128_52939359) for the suggestion):

```
val o_data=val files = (1 to 30)map(d =>f"test::repo/shared/[2018-09-$d%02d]")
```

**Edit 2:** since these are file names, we can use file API to read them:

```
val allLines:mutable.Buffer[String] = mutable.Buffer()
o_data.foreach(filename => {
  val lines = tes.read(filename)
  allLines.append(line)
  ... //do stuff with lines read from file: "filename"
}
allLines foreach println
```

Of course, you should be mindful of any errors that might arise from reading a bunch of files (file not exists, etc). The `foreach` loop reads filenames present in o_data and will process them one by one. You can see [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-open-read-text-files-in-scala-cookbook-examples) to see a few examples on how to open and read files.

**Edit 3:** Aggregating all lines in the files can be achieved using a more functional style too:

```
import scala.io.Source.fromFile
val allLines = files.foldLeft(Iterator[String]())((f, g) => f ++ fromFile(g).getLines)
allLines foreach println
```

The advantage of this method is that it concatenates iterators which may help if files are large. If it is desired to get strings, the following can be done:

```
import scala.io.Source.fromFile
val allLines = files.foldLeft(List[String]())((f, g) => f ++ fromFile(g).getLines.toList)
allLines foreach println
```

This method can be successful with any file reading technique that reaturns lines in the file (`data.read` in the OP's question).

Comment: your one liner looks beautiful

Comment: the data is TSV format, and since I'm more familiar with Python, my plan was to aggregate all the 30 files into one using scala and use a function to turn it into a pandas dataframe for the analysis

Comment: @Si_CPyR, I added another edit. Please check if it answers the question.

Comment: o_data.foreach(filename => {
  val lines = tes.read(filename)
}

Comment: not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I'm running into 'failed to parse - incomplete' error

Comment: Even better one-liner: `f"test::repo/shared[2018-09-$d%02d]"`

Comment: @Dima, thanks, I updated the answer with the suggestion

Comment: @Si_CPyR, if your `tes.read` method can read single filename, it should be able to read an array of them one by one too. Check if the format strictly adheres to the specification in the question.  I may have dropped a slash or another character somewhere. You can do a `println` inside the loop before `read` to confirm the validity of the input.

Comment: ok, thanks. But will it guarantee the data variable to have all the files combined? Meaning it will have dates from 9/1~9/30 in a single variable

Comment: @Si_CPyR, I don't quite understand your question about the guarantee. We are building the array with the values we want. So yes, it is guaranteed all dates from 1 to 30 will be in there and nothing else.

Comment: I understand that o_data.foreach... is iterating through each of 30 values in o_data, but was unsure which part of the code actually merges the files together into one. Sounds like from what you're saying 'lines' will have all the data.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to combine all the data in these files into one big list of strings?

Comment: @jrook Yes, since the original format of the file is TSV, one giant strings separated by tabs containing all the dates from 9/1~9/30.

Comment: Some months have 31 days...?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach, the OP wanted the range `9/1~9/30`

Comment: I feel like an idiot, first time I read it I thought it was some strange range or month specification. when really it's `9/1 to 9/30`

Answer (score 1):

To get the range for any month, use the java.time library. Check this out

```
scala> val o_data =  (1 to 31)
o_data: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)

scala> val (year,month) = (2018,9)
year: Int = 2018
month: Int = 9

scala> o_data.map( x => { val y=java.time.LocalDate.of(year,month,1); y.plusDays(x-1)} ).filter( _.getMonthValue==month).map(s"test::repo/shared/["+_.toString+"]").foreach(println)
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-01]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-02]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-03]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-04]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-05]
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-06]
.........
test::repo/shared/[2018-09-30]

scala>
```